# identifier is undefined in ATL\WTL application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wtl

I've created new ATL\WTL project in Visual Studio 2010.

I've got red lines under `CAppModule`,`CMessageLoop`  and etc. with error

> identifier is undefined

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the proper headers. For example `CAppModule` is defined in `atlapp.h` so you need `#include <atlapp.h>`.

Comment: You should mention that `<atlapp.h>` is part of the Windows Template Library. I had to go open 20+ search terms just to find out about this. I'm a noobie at WTL/ATL by the way.

Comment: @tom_mai78101, sorry I just assumed that anyone working on a WTL app would have the headers available.